# Delphi list index of bounds

Tags: delphi

Всем доброго времени суток.

Есть такой код:

```
  if trim(edt12.Text) <> '' then
  begin
    Tag1.LoadFromFile(edt12.Text);
    stext:=StringReplace(stext, '$tag1', Tag1[RandomRange(0 , Tag1.Count-1)], [rfReplaceAll, rfIgnoreCase]);
  end;
    if trim(edt13.Text) <> '' then
  begin
    Tag2.LoadFromFile(edt13.Text);
    stext:=StringReplace(stext, '$tag2', Tag2[RandomRange(0 , Tag2.Count-1)], [rfReplaceAll, rfIgnoreCase]);
  end;
    if trim(edt14.Text) <> '' then
  begin
    Tag2.LoadFromFile(edt14.Text);
    stext:=StringReplace(stext, '$tag3', Tag3[RandomRange(0 , Tag3.Count-1)], [rfReplaceAll, rfIgnoreCase]);
  end;
```

Получаю ошибку `list index of bounds -1`. Как помню эта ошибка означает обращение к несуществующему элементу. Однако тут вроде как все правильно.

Comment: В какой строке ошибка? -1 может получиться, если в каком-то из `Tag` `Count` = 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Код сделан копипастой, отсюдова и ошибки. В коде есть три if-блока. В первом работают с Tag1, в втором с Tag2, а в третьем и с Tag3 и с Tag2. Так как текст в Tag3 скорее всего не загружен, то вот она проблема.

Как бы я для начала сделал. Сделал дополнительную процедуру.

```
procedure repl(text:string, tag:string, memo:TMemo, var stext:string);
begin
  if trim(text) <> '' then
  begin
    memo.LoadFromFile(text);
    stext:=StringReplace(stext, tag, memo[RandomRange(0 , memo.Count-1)], [rfReplaceAll, rfIgnoreCase]);

  end;

repl(edt12.Text, '$tag1', Tag1, stext);
repl(edt13.Text, '$tag2', Tag2, stext);
repl(edt14.Text, '$tag3', Tag3, stext);
```

код стал явно понятнее, и что самое главное, теперь можно добавить ещё десяток edit/memo и не боятся сделать ошибку. Но я бы логику кода пересмотрел немного.